# How to dynamically trigger build jobs?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a Jenkins pipeline that triggers multiple build jobs on a single project. Each build job has different parameters that dynamically get generated during the job. There's also a string parameter on which slave the job should run on. That list is a multi-line string that gets split by \n.

This is what I've got:

```
def projectName = "${PROJECT_NAME}"
def slaveList = "${SLAVE_LIST}".split("\n")

def gradleTasks = "${GRADLE_TASKS}"

def slaveClosure = { slaveNum ->
    build job: projectName, parameters: [
                    [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'slaveAol', label: slaveList[slaveNum]],
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'gradleTasks', value: gradleTasks]
                ]
}

def parallelSlaveMap = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < slaveList.size(); i++) {
    parallelSlaveMap.put("slave${i}", slaveClosure(i))
}

parallel(parallelSlaveMap)
```

But this got me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a closure or failFast but found slave0=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@5caff0a8
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ParallelStep.java:202)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:134)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:113)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:44)
```

For reference, line 44 in the script is the "parallel" line.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to dynamically create parallel build jobs based on a parameter list of slaves.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `slaveClosure(i)` initializes an object and assigns it to the map, which is unexpected by jenkins. If you were to use this pattern, you would probably need an outer function around the closure, which returns the closure without evaluating it. Instead, I use the following method to spawn parallel jobs. Storing the index value in each iteration is important since the closure is evaluated at runtime.

```
def projectName = "${PROJECT_NAME}"
def slaveList = "${SLAVE_LIST}".split("\n")
def slaveMap = [:]
def gradleTasks = "${GRADLE_TASKS}"

for (int i = 0; i < slaveList.size(); i++) {
    def index = i
    slaveMap['slave' + index] = {build job: projectName, parameters: [
                    [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'slaveAol', label: slaveList[index]],
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'gradleTasks', value: gradleTasks]
                ]
    }
}

parallel slaveMap
```